# How to change snap user directory?

Tags: snapshot

I use Fedora.

I wonder how I can configure snap to store all snapshots not in ~/snap/... but rather in ~/X/snap/...

Sorry, I have already tried looking at various documentation of snapd but could not figure this out. I figured only out that I might have to redefine SNAP_USER_DATA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1575053) bug report it seems that it is still in the wishlist and open. So **no**, it is not possible to change the default directory of `snapd`.